# Обращения одномерного динамического массива в N-мерный

Tags: c++, c

Всем доброго времени суток, вот такой вопрос. Есть такая задача: "Напишите функцию для обращения одномерного динамического массива в N-мерный." Есть идеи как это можно реализовать, просто натолкните, буду благодарен. Не совсем представляю как можно из одномерного массива делать многомерный и каждый раз разный.

Comment: http://www.kabit.ru/ru/post/N-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2.html

Comment: А без ООП это реально сделать?

Comment: Да - все функции класса реализуете рядом с main и все

Comment: Почему нет? Выкинуть все классы, вместо них глобальные переменные.

Comment: Лучше все-таки обойтись без глобальных переменных.

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться